# PowerMockito testing for rabbitmq akka streams

Tags: java-8, rabbitmq, akka-stream

I am writing some testcases using RabbitMq library provided by

```
io.scalac.amqp
```

The testcase is to test consume message scenario, the code for which is something like and runs fine.

```
Source<Object, NotUsed> src = Source.fromPublisher(conn.consume(props.getQueue(), 1, false)).map(msg -> {
    //some transformation to `ByteString` from "`Delivery`" msg
}
```

conn above is `io.scalac.amqp.impl.RabbitConnection` passed as `io.scalac.amqp.impl.Connection`
Parent class `io.scalac.amqp.impl.Connection` returns `Publisher<Delivery>`
while `io.scalac.amqp.impl.RabbitConnection` returns `QueuePublisher`

I write the testcase using PowerMock and spy `Source` class and mock like this

```
Source<Delivery,NotUsed> del;//Creating this object before calling the test

PowerMockito.spy(Source.class);  
PowerMockito.when(Source.fromPublisher(Mockito.isA(Publisher.class))).thenReturn(del);
    //Also tried
//PowerMockito.when(Source.fromPublisher(Mockito.isA(QueuePublisher.class))).thenReturn(del);
```

Is there any way I can test the consuming code through mocks?